# Access enums through command line

Tags: java, command-line, enums

```
enum Child {
    David(23),
    Johnson(34),
    Brackley(19);
  }

  int age;

  Child(int age) {
    this.age=age; 
  }

  void getAge() {
    return age; 
  }

  public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    ---------------------
  }
}
```

If I had to enter command line arguments, for eg. if I enter java Test David
Then it should print "23".

So how can we access enums through command line.. ? what should be written in main method?

Please explain..

Comment: Your braces do not match

Comment: Please don't change the code in the question, no matter how wrong it is: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101583/when-is-it-appropriate-to-edit-someone-elses-code?rq=1. The proper code can be shown in the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to convert the String arg from the command line to an enum value.

```
Child c = Child.valueOf(args[0]);
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`Enum.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29). It takes an enum class and string as as argument and tries and find an enum by that name.

Note: throws `IllegalArgumentException` if not found... You'll have to catch it explicitly since this is an unchecked exception.

Another solution is to use `.valueOf()` on your enum class itself (`MyEnum.valueOf("whatever")`). Same warning as to exception handling applies.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution:

```
public enum Child {

    David(23),
    Johnson(34),
    Brackley(19);

    private int age;

    private Child(int age) {
        this.age=age; 
    }

    int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public static Child getAgeFromName(String name) {
        for(Child child : Child.values()) {
            if(child.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                return child;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(args.length != 0) {
            Child child = Child.getAgeFromName(args[0]);
            if(child != null) {
                System.out.println(args[0] + " age is " + child.getAge());
            }else {
                System.out.println("No child exists with name " + args[0]);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("please provide a child name");
        }


    }
}
```

INPUT   : OUTPUT
java Child David :  David age is 23
java Child sam : No child exist with name sam
java Child    : Please provide a child name

Hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
enum Child {
   David(23),
   Johnson(34),
   Brackley(19);

 int age;

 Child(int age) {
   this.age=age; 
 }

 public int getAge() {
   return age; 
 }

   public static void main(String args[]) 
   {
       for(Child c : Child.values())
       {
               //Here you can check for you equality of name taken as command line arg
           System.out.println("Name is " + c + " and age is " + c.getAge());
       }
   }

}
```

output is as follows

```
Name is David and age is 23
Name is Johnson and age is 34
Name is Brackley and age is 19
```